# Why applyDimension method returns wrong values?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I was adding some code in the onMeasure method of a custom view in order to ensure a minimum physical dimensions to be sure the user will not have problems clicking it. The fact is that I wanted to ensure 8 millimeters of height but meanwhile in some devices seems to work properly it does not work in the Samsung Galaxy S II. which for the expected 8mm I get something less than 5mm drawn on the screen, which is smaller and the view cannot be clicked properly. In order to be sure the issue was in the device I created a small program to test it, the code of the main activity is the following one:

```
public class TrialMillimetersActivity extends Activity {

    private static final float FINGER_WIDTH = 8.0f;
    private static final int FINGER_WIDTH_UNITS = TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("DisplayMetrics:" +
            "\n  Screen resolution in pixels: " +
            metrics.widthPixels + "x" + metrics.heightPixels +
            "\n  Screen density (dpi): " + metrics.densityDpi +
            "\n  Scale for text: " + metrics.scaledDensity);

        final float minFingerWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            FINGER_WIDTH_UNITS, FINGER_WIDTH, metrics);
        tv.append("\n\nThe platform returns for " + FINGER_WIDTH +
            "mm the number of " + minFingerWidth + " pixels on this device.");

        final float widthMm = FINGER_WIDTH * (metrics.widthPixels) / minFingerWidth;
        final float heightMm = FINGER_WIDTH * (metrics.heightPixels) / minFingerWidth;
        tv.append("\n\nThis means this screen has a resolution of " + widthMm + "x" +
            heightMm + " in millimeters.");

        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I tried the code above in different devices and, even as there are not exact, the are very close to the screen dimensions (measured by a ruler). But not in the Galaxy S II.

Could someone tell me how to work around this issue or, in case of an error in the code, tell me what is the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on two SII devices here, one with the stock rom and the other with Cyanogenmod (Kitkat), and both report the screen of 56x93.33mm which is fairly accurate.

If you are using the same applyDimension call in your custom view it should work.

You can try something different as a final test, using that dimension to draw a simple View and setting its width by code. Maybe the custom view flow modifies the final view size.